# Tamil characters appear as question marks when using JSTL fmt library and properties files

Tags: jsp, character-encoding, jstl, properties-file, tamil

I am using JSTL `fmt` taglib to show Tamil characters. But I could not show any Tamil characters. Instead of showing Tamil characters, it's showing question mark characters as in `??????`. I tried for Hindi and it shows question marks as well. What should I do now?

Here is my code. I simply try to print Hello World in Tamil.

`fileproperty.properties`:

```
helloworld=வணக்கம் உலகம்
```

`Hello.jsp`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <fmt:setLocale value="ta-IN"/>
  <fmt:setBundle basename="fileproperty"/>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <fmt:message key="helloworld"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the encoding on your JSP file? I'd recommend you use UTF-8.

Comment: JSPs do not support any fonts - fonts are handled by the browser. If your browser supports Tamil fonts, the issue is likely an encoding defect. This can occur in the source code and/or the application metadata. It would help if you provided some sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Properties files do not support UTF-8. Read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

> ... the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding ...

*(as you seem to be using Eclipse, I wonder if you have ever actually carefully read the warning message which it would show while saving such a `.properties` file for the first time)*

Basically, you need the `native2ascii` tool to convert UTF-8 saved properties files to proper ISO-8859-1 properties file format. Rename your UTF-8 properties file to include `utf8` somewhere in the filename and convert it as follows:

```
native2ascii –encoding UTF-8 fileproperty.utf8.properties fileproperty.properties
```

Hereby any character which is not covered by the ISO-8859-1 charset will be replaced by an unicode codepoint sequence like `\u1234`.

However, Eclipse has already builtin support for it. You should make use of it. You should be opening properties files in a "Properties file editor" instead of a "Text editor" (it's recognizable by the property values being highlighted in blue instead of unhighlighted in black). If it doesn't do that by default already, rightclick the properties file and choose *Open With > Properties File Editor*. If you paste `வணக்கம் உலகம்`, then Eclipse will (should) automatically convert it to `\u0BB5\u0BA3\u0B95\u0BCD\u0B95\u0BAE\u0BCD \u0B89\u0BB2\u0B95\u0BAE\u0BCD\u008D`.

Save it once again, clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart and try once again. It should now work fine.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your `@page` is full of values which are already the default. Just the following is sufficient.

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in you jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

**Change file encoding** in your message.properties -> **properties** -> **Resource** -> **text file encoding** -> *UTF8*

And review in your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml this messageSource bean:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:project" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```